# jquery rotate resets size and position?

Tags: jquery, rotation

I am using the [jquery rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/).

When I call it on an `img` element that has a specific width and height (*that is not the actual width and height of the source image*.) The rotation is applied accurately however it resets the width and height to match the source image. Also if the image is positioned, it removes its positioning and sets it inline.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I advice you to, look into the source code & modify the code according to your requirement

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is that the plugin creates a new image from the source image but fails to take its current width and height into account. Note that it actually already works correctly in Internet Explorer, because it rotates the original image with some Microsoft-only matrix transform mechanism. If you look at line 27 and following, where the "good browser logic" is applied:

```
    } else {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if (!p.oImage) {
        canvas.oImage = new Image();
        canvas.oImage.src = p.src;
    } else {
        canvas.oImage = p.oImage;
    }
```

Now if you include the width and height here it works in Firefox as well:

```
    } else {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if (!p.oImage) {
        canvas.oImage = new Image();
        canvas.oImage.width = p.width; // ADDED
        canvas.oImage.height = p.height; // ADDED
        canvas.oImage.src = p.src;
    } else {
        canvas.oImage = p.oImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery rotate plugin uses the size of the image instead of the size of the HTML object.

You need to get the size of your object first, and then set the width and height that you wish to use with something like this at the beginning of the plugin :

```
var imageHeight = $(yourImageContainer).height();
var imageWidth = $(yourImageContainer).width();
```

Once you have your variables set, use them whenever the image is redrawn in the plugin. 
A new img element is created and your image will be drawn on it. Instead of using the size of the image, use the size from the variables (see my comment in the code)

```
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(angle,whence) {
    var imageHeight = $(yourImageContainer).height();
    var imageWidth = $(yourImageContainer).width();


    var p = this.get(0);

    if (!whence) {
        p.angle = ((p.angle==undefined?0:p.angle) + angle) % 360;
    } else {
        p.angle = angle;
    }

    if (p.angle >= 0) {
        var rotation = Math.PI * p.angle / 180;
    } else {
        var rotation = Math.PI * (360+p.angle) / 180;
    }
    var costheta = Math.cos(rotation);
    var sintheta = Math.sin(rotation);

    if (document.all && !window.opera) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('img');


            //The size of the object is set here. MODIFY IT HERE
        canvas.src = p.src;
        canvas.height = p.height;
        canvas.width = p.width;

        canvas.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+costheta+",M12="+(-sintheta)+",M21="+sintheta+",M22="+costheta+",SizingMethod='auto expand')";
    } else {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        if (!p.oImage) {
            canvas.oImage = new Image();
            canvas.oImage.src = p.src;
        } else {
            canvas.oImage = p.oImage;
        }

        canvas.style.width = canvas.width = Math.abs(costheta*canvas.oImage.width) + Math.abs(sintheta*canvas.oImage.height);
        canvas.style.height = canvas.height = Math.abs(costheta*canvas.oImage.height) + Math.abs(sintheta*canvas.oImage.width);

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.save();
        if (rotation <= Math.PI/2) {
            context.translate(sintheta*canvas.oImage.height,0);
        } else if (rotation <= Math.PI) {
            context.translate(canvas.width,-costheta*canvas.oImage.height);
        } else if (rotation <= 1.5*Math.PI) {
            context.translate(-costheta*canvas.oImage.width,canvas.height);
        } else {
            context.translate(0,-sintheta*canvas.oImage.width);
        }
        context.rotate(rotation);
        context.drawImage(canvas.oImage, 0, 0, canvas.oImage.width, canvas.oImage.height);
        context.restore();
    }
    canvas.id = p.id;
    canvas.angle = p.angle;
    p.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, p);
}

jQuery.fn.rotateRight = function(angle) {
    this.rotate(angle==undefined?90:angle);
}

jQuery.fn.rotateLeft = function(angle) {
    this.rotate(angle==undefined?-90:-angle);
}
```

As for the positioning, do you position it with an inline style? If so, you will obviously lose it when the HTML element is created from scratch. You shouldn't lose it with a css class though (add your class in the jQuery plugin if needed).

You should probably make the size an option of this pluging instead of using a hardcoded selector. It will be much simpler to reuse :

```
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(angle,whence, imageWidth, imageHeight) { ... }
```